# Create Direction Arrows (arrow heads) on polyline in obj c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-maps

I have been searching for a quite while but couldn't find any answer to this, anyways, I am working on `Google Maps` for iOS using Obj C and have drawn routes (`polyline`) using multiple coordinates provided to me by the server in the form of an array. But the problem is that I want to show `arrow heads` on that line so that the direction can be seen on the map. Please help.

Comment: See this question [How to calculate the coordinates of a arrowhead based on the arrow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316180/how-to-calculate-the-coordinates-of-a-arrowhead-based-on-the-arrow). It doesn't give an Obj-C answer, but the algorithm is there and writing it in Obj-C is straightforward. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function which draws a nice little arrow line. It has some parameters you can tweak:

```
void TRDrawLineWithArrow(CGContextRef CXT, CGPoint FROMPOINT, CGPoint TOPOINT, CGFloat WIDTH, CGFloat ARROWSIZEMULTIPLE)
{
    CGFloat         rise = TOPOINT.y - FROMPOINT.y;
    CGFloat         run = TOPOINT.x - FROMPOINT.x;

    // trig
    CGFloat         length = sqrt(rise*rise + run+run);
    CGFloat         angle = atan2(rise, run);

    // the length of our arrowhead
    CGFloat         arrowLen = WIDTH*ARROWSIZEMULTIPLE;

    // push graphics context
    CGContextSaveGState(CXT);

    // transform context according to line's origin and angle
    CGContextTranslateCTM(CXT, FROMPOINT.x, FROMPOINT.y);
    CGContextRotateCTM(CXT, angle);

    // draw straight line
    CGContextMoveToPoint(CXT, 0, -WIDTH/2.);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(CXT, 0, WIDTH/2.);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(CXT, length-arrowLen, WIDTH/2.);

    // draw arrowhead
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(CXT, length-arrowLen, (WIDTH*ARROWSIZEMULTIPLE)/2.);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(CXT, length, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(CXT, length-arrowLen, -(WIDTH*ARROWSIZEMULTIPLE)/2.);

    CGContextAddLineToPoint(CXT, length-arrowLen, -WIDTH/2.);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(CXT, 0, -WIDTH/2.);

    // fill the path
    CGContextFillPath(CXT);

    // pop graphics context
    CGContextRestoreGState(CXT);
}
```

You would call it from a UIView like this:

```
CGContextRef cxt = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(cxt, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);

TRDrawLineWithArrow(cxt, CGPointMake(10,10), CGPointMake(300,100), 5, 3);
```

Comment: what do i use in fromPoint, toPoint ? because i got two coordinates in terms of latitude and longitude. @TyR

Comment: This answer is completely devoid of google maps SDK!